# Automation for paired end reads with Cutadapt

Tags: bioinformatics

I am trying to automate my paired-end reads with cutadapt, but I keep encountering the same issue - the adapter is trimmed from the forward reads, but not from the reverse. Even after modifying the code according to the documentation, the problem remains. If I only trim the forward or the reverse alone, it works, but not as a paired-end job.

This is my code:

```
cat ids.txt | parallel 'cutadapt -j 24 -a AGATCGGAA --interleaved {}_R1.fq.gz {}_R2.fq.gz | cutadapt -j 24 -a AGATCGGAA --interleaved -o {}clipped_R1.fq.gz -p {}clipped_R2.fq.gz -'
```

Does anyone have a tip on how to modify this code to make it work? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You may be interested in the stackexchange site dedicated to bioinformatics: https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check carefully the `cutadapt` documentation, there's a specific chapter regarding paired end alignments. You are looking for `-A`.

You are also messing things up with the `--interleaved` parameter: if the reads are interleaved, why are you giving the two ends? I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve, but I bet you have an extra `cutadapt` invocation.

I guess you are trying something like:

```
cat ids.txt | parallel 'cutadapt -j 24 -a AGATCGGAA -A <proper_adaptor> -o {}clipped_R1.fq.gz -p {}clipped_R2.fq.gz {}_R1.fq.gz {}_R2.fq.gz'
```

Comment: Thank you, yes I was a bit confused about the interleaved thing. I ran it in the format you suggested and it worked perfectly! Thank you!!

Comment: If it solved your problem, it would be nice if you mark my answer as acepted :-)

Comment: Of course! Sorry! Noob here. I think I checked it now.

Comment: :-) Good job! That's the standard procedure once you find the better answer for your needs.